# WebView can not load two different urls in flutter?

Tags: flutter, webview

I print the url message at the first line in build method. And here, the url is right, but the webView has no effect.
I use the webview_flutter lib, and the version is 0.3.13;

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(WebPage());

class WebPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _WebPageState();
  }
}

class _WebPageState extends State<WebPage> {
  String url = "https://flutter.dev/";

  void _changeUrl() {
    setState(() {
      this.url = "https://github.com/flutter/flutter";
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("url:" + url);
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("WebPage"),
          ),
          body: WebView(
            initialUrl: url,
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: _changeUrl,
            child: Icon(Icons.replay),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

I excepted the webView load the second url, but it not.

Answer (score 4):

you need to use web-view controller class methods like this

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(WebPage());

class WebPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _WebPageState();
  }
}

class _WebPageState extends State<WebPage> {
  WebViewController controller;
  var url = "https://flutter.dev/";

  changeUrl() {
    setState(() {
    url = "https://github.com/flutter/flutter";
      controller.loadUrl(url);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("url:" + url);
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("WebPage"),
          ),
    body: WebView(
          // key: _key,
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          initialUrl: url,
          onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
            controller = webViewController;
          }),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          changeUrl();
        },
            child: Icon(Icons.replay),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

more methods to controller could be found here [flutter web-view class methods](https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/webview_flutter/WebViewController-class.html)

Comment: It works. But I want to find a better solution. And I want to know why this code is failed?